# Can I make Visual Studio show a notification or alert when I open a particular project or solution

Tags: visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-2019

I would like to perform an action upon opening a particular Visual Studio 15/17/19 solution.

I need to inform anyone who is about to work on the project that there are important notes (included in the project) that they should read first.  Ideally it would be a pop up so as to be very obvious.

When googling I can only find solutions that involve Visual Studio extensions but I need something that does not rely on anyone else doing anything (e.g. installing the extension) - it needs to be something dependent only on the project itself.

I'm hoping for something that I can add in the .sln or .scproj file that VS will see when it loads the solution and take action, but anything that achieves the same purpose would be good.

I'd be grateful if someone is able to let me know how I can achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You've got an extension called [**Solution Open Pop Up**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=GregTrevellick.SolutionOpenPopUp) supported on many versions of Visual Studio.

In the **Overview** tab there is a **Features** section where you can see a short example of how to use it. From the extension's website:

> If a file called SolutionOpenPopUp.txt and/or ReadMe.txt exists in the root folder of the solution, the contents are shown in a pop-up when the solution is open.

Comment: Hi, if a different programmer opens the solution without installing the extension will the file still display?  Thanks

Comment: @SimonBarnett It won't, in that case I guess you should include something like a "README.txt" in the project or maybe some comment section at the beginning of the main file that gets the attention of the programmers. I've also tried to google **"visual studio on solution open event"**. Have a look at that, but i'm not sure if it is what you are looking for.